# Can't read from AudioRecord when encoding is PCM-Float

Tags: android, xamarin, audiorecord

No matter what I do, I can't get the Android AudioRecord class to work with Pcm-Float.

Here is my code:

```
public AndroidAudioDriver(Sensor sensor, int desiredSampleRate)
{
    _sensor = sensor;

    if (!InitialiseSampleRate(desiredSampleRate))
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("No supported audio sample rates found");
    }
    recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.Mic, SampleRate, ChannelIn.Mono, Encoding.PcmFloat, _bufferSize);
    _recorder.StartRecording();
    var res = _recorder.Read(_audioData, 0, (int)(SampleRate * _readPortion));
}

private bool InitialiseSampleRate(int rate)
{
    for (int i = rate; i < 48000; i += 100)
    {  // add the rates you wish to check against
        _bufferSize = AudioRecord.GetMinBufferSize(i, ChannelIn.Mono, Encoding.Pcm16bit) * 10;
        if (_bufferSize > 0)
        {
            _audioData = new byte[_bufferSize];
            SampleRate = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

`_recorder.read` always returns -3, which according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) is "ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION". The same code works just fine with Pcm-16bit. I don't know what the invalid operation is, and there aren't any errors in logcat that I can see.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the device API level that you are testing on?

Comment: Minimum version is API 21, compiled using Android 7.1, running on a phone with API 23.

Comment: On your API-21 / API-22 devices you will not have `PcmFloat` available when using AudioRecord

Comment: Documentation says that PcmFloat was added in API 21?

Comment: `AudioTrack` in API-21 (`L`) added supported for PCMFloat, but `AudioRecord` did not get it till API-23 (`M`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use PcmFloat with AudioRecord, you must use the overload :

`AudioRecord.Read(float[], offset, count, readType)`.

The issue was I was passing it a byte[], which appears to only work with Pcm8bit and Pcm16bit.

Answer (score 1):

> AudioRecord as of API M and AudioTrack as of API LOLLIPOP support ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT.

So on your API-21 / API-22 devices you will not have `PcmFloat` available

API-23 (Marshmallow) added support for `PcmFloat` for `AudioRecord`.

Comment: I changed the minimum version to API 23, still get the same -3 error code.